# Conversion of Mapped drive path to UNC doesn't work in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, unc, mapped-drive

I am working on web application where we have some mapped drives. I want to get the UNC path from Mapped drive.

I am using WNetGetConnection to get UNC path. It works perfectly when i run it from visual studio but it doesn't work when i check the same application by deploying to IIS. I get below when i run it from IIS.

Error 2250
The network connection could not be found.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f79f2b3-d092-431f-bc28-d15d93cf5d09/c-how-to-convert-a-mapped-directory-into-a-full-directory-name?forum=csharpgeneral

Can somebody help me resolve this? Why it doesn't work from IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: Mapped drives are a per-user concept. *you* may have a drive mapped from the machine where IIS is running, but does the user account that the application pool is running under also have that same drive mapped?

Comment: Do you mean the App pool identity user should have access to mapped drive? How to check if user account that the application pool is running under also have that same drive mapped?

Comment: Anybody who can help?